# set ios screen resolution in xcode4 storyboard

Tags: interface-builder, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

Am working on an ipod/iphone application that primarily captures a photo. Am designing the flow in xcode4 IB storyboard. [image]

However, as you can see from the image it is taking the default resolution as 320x480 which causing the preview on ipod retina display to show up in a corner than full screen. How can I make the IB get device resolution and adjust the ratio accordingly?

I tried looking at project settings, build settings, info.plist however couldn't find an answer yet.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those dimensions are in points, not pixels.  They are correct.  On retina displays, 320 points are equal to 640 pixels.  If your application is only showing up in a quarter of the screen, it's likely the problem is in your code, not in how you have set things up in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized it after making some tweaks to the video orientation. However, its good to know that 320 are points and not pixels.